# I want to schedule the email send for some choosen date . How can I do that in DRF?

Tags: django, email, django-rest-framework, schedule, apscheduler

I want to take the receiver email address  and schedule date as an input and send mail to the schedule date. I have following lines of code in **views.py**
Actually I'm looking forward to use **apscheduler** package for **async background task** in django but **any suggestions and solutions are appreciable**.

```
class SendMailView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    '''
    POST Method for sending Email
    '''     
       send_to = request.data.get('receiver_email') 
       schedule_for = request.data.get('schedule_date')

       email_plaintext_message = " Hello"
       send_mail(
                # title:
                "Test mail,
                # message:
                email_plaintext_message,
                # from:
                 'some@gmail.com,
                # to:
                [send_to]

            )


       return Response({"status":"Email Send"},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I just moved from the apscheduler to celery... is it something you would consider?

Comment: Sure @Walucas would love to hear more  , please feel free . Note that i want to take the receiver email address in request body.

Comment: I will post as an answer then, but leave the details for you, give me a sec

Comment: @Walcuas just curious to know reason why did you moved from apscheduler to celery ?

Comment: I was on a situation where same process was being scheduled on more than one instance, and I didnt want that.... I had three instances, and all those were firing my task, so I needed something external that could manage this

Comment: @Walucas Same here , that my job are executing twice .. here is the detail what happened it to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888786/apscheduler-job-in-django-executes-twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/).
All you need to do is follow the installation, start a worker and the beat, with that you can scheduler tasks.

**task.py**

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def sendScheduledEmail(email_to):
   #do your stuff
```

And on your API POST you schedule that:

```
sendScheduledEmail.apply_async([email_to],eta=datetime.datetime(2021, 07, 06, 09, 30))
```

I didnt test this, so let me know if you get any errors

Comment: Sure will test on it !!  , btw will the worker continues running even after the mail is sent right ?