# Apscheduler Job in Django executes twice

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, scheduler, apscheduler

The scheduled job executes twice with difference in nanoseconds. I have a task as follows in **task.py**

```
def print_hello():
   print("time-->",datetime.datetime.now())
   print("hello")

def print_world():
   print("time-->",datetime.datetime.now())
   print("hello")

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler1 = BackgroundScheduler()
```

Add in app.py from app folder consist following code line..

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from datetime import date
class ExploitDataConfig(AppConfig):
     name = 'exploit_data' 

     def ready(self):
    
         from exploit_data import task   

         task.scheduler.add_job(task.print_hello, 'interval', minutes=5)
         task.scheduler1.add_job(task.print_world, 'interval', minutes=5
         task.scheduler.start()
         task.scheduler1.start()
```

I want this **to execute only once** at the interval of 5 minutes.
**ANY HELP IS APPRECIABLE ..**

Comment: Which task is executing twice? the `print_hello`?

Comment: @sur.la.route yes both the print_hello  and the print_world

Comment: You can try simple-scheduler [https://pypi.org/project/simple_scheduler/]. It works in background by default. Also you can tag the same function with different names any number of times. [https://github.com/Vernal-Inertia/simple_scheduler/blob/main/examples/recurring.py]

Comment: @Tanveer How to schedule job for specific date ?

Comment: @manojadhikari job for specific date is still a work in progress[see issues tab]. Is your present issue resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this can help for temporary solution:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: thanks it works , but I don't think this is the standard solution of the problem though ..

Comment: This works but doesn't really solve the underlying problem and makes development a pain.